# Riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis

Why is the Dirichlet function,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x : x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\ 0 : x \notin \mathbb{Q}, \end{cases}$$

not Riemann integrable on any interval $[a, b]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\mathbb Q$ is dense and discrete in $\mathbb R$, so
$$\sup_{x\in[\xi,\eta]} f(x) = \eta \neq 0 = \inf_{x\in[\xi,\eta]} f(x)$$
Thus, $U(f;[a,b],Z) > 0=L(f;[a,b],Z)$ for any partiton $Z$

---

[I have edited to reflect $f(x) = x\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)$, the previous version was designed for $f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)$]

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I don't recognise anything in the answer! Is there any way you could explain it using Riemann sums?

Comment: @user2850514 $U$ denotes the upper riemann sum and $L$ the lower. They are defined by
$$U(f;[a,b],Z) = \sum_{I\in Z} |I| \sup_{x\in I} f(x)$$
and
$$L(f;[a,b],Z) = \sum_{I\in Z} |I| \inf_{x\in I} f(x)$$
where $I$ are the intervals in $Z$, $[a,b] = \bigcup_{I\in Z} I$ and $|I|$ is the interval length.

Comment: Does this help or will you provide your notational conventions so I can adapt the answer to it?

Comment: I am not familiar with sup and inf, more familiar with the terminology Steven has used.

Comment: @user2850514 Unfortunately, the definition of a Riemann integral heavily relies on $\inf$ and $\sup$. You could substitute them for $\min$ and $\max$ if the interval endpoints are chosen to be rational.

Comment: Can you explain what they are? I may know of them in a different form

Comment: $\inf$ is the "biggest lower bound". That means it coincides with the minimum $\min$ if there is a point wich attains it. It's somewhat a generalisation of $\min$, since
$$\inf [0,1] = \min [0,1] = 0$$
but $\min (0,1]$ doesn't exist and $\inf (0,1] = 0$. The analogous is for $\sup$ and $\max$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) for details

Comment: @AlexR you are actually using the, conceptually cleaner, Darboux integral rather than the Riemann integral.  The two notions of integrability are equivalent.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Thanks for the hint. It was introduced to me as the Riemann integral in my first calculus lessons (it's been a while though). It should be noted that the two arising definitions of integrability are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Say $a,b$ are positive. No matter what partition of the interval you choose, you can always pick a rational representative.  The Riemann sum is then the same as the riemann sum for $f(x) = x$, so you get $(b-a)/2$  However, if you were to always pick an irrational representative of each subinterval, you would get $0$. These answers are different, so the limit of the sequence of Riemann sums depends on the choice of the representatives.  So it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I have attempted to find the Riemann sum of both, although am stuggling to work with the summations for rational $x$.

Comment: You do not need to.  If you choose all your $x_i$ rational, then the sum you get is exactly a riemann sum for the function $f(x)=x$, which you should already know how to integrate.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Following on from that, what if we have an interval [-a, a], an integral of such would give 0, so do we modify and consider above and below the curve?

Comment: In that case, you can choose rational representatives in $[-a,0)$ and irrational representatives in $[0,a]$; or vice versa. The two choices give different answers, as before.